# Context menu in CollectionView

Tags: c#, maui

Would it be possible to have a context menu appear when clicking on one of the lines of a CollectionView please?

(My application targets Android, iOs and Windows)

Thanks

Comment: See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data?view=net-maui-8.0#context-menus)

Comment: @jason thank you but I have already read it, and it does not answer my request (a menu appearing when clicking) 

Answer (score 0):

> My application targets Android, iOs and Windows

From document [Display a context menu in a .NET MAUI desktop app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/context-menu?view=net-maui-8.0),we could know that:

> In .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI), a context menu can be added
> to any control that derives from Element, on **Mac Catalyst and Windows**.

So, if you use `a context menu`, you cannot target all the three platforms you mentioned above.

But as a workaround, you can use [SwipeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/swipeview?view=net-maui-8.0) instead.

A usage example:

```
   <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <SwipeView>
                <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                    <SwipeItems>
                        <SwipeItem Text="Favorite"
                                   IconImageSource="favorite.png"
                                   BackgroundColor="LightGreen"
                                   Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference collectionView}, Path=BindingContext.FavoriteCommand}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                        <SwipeItem Text="Delete"
                                   IconImageSource="delete.png"
                                   BackgroundColor="LightPink"
                                   Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference collectionView}, Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    </SwipeItems>
                </SwipeView.LeftItems>
                <Grid BackgroundColor="White"
                      Padding="10">
                    <!-- Define item appearance -->
                </Grid>
            </SwipeView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

**Note:**

For more information, please check document [Context menus of CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data?view=net-maui-8.0#context-menus).

You can also check the official sample here : [VerticalListSwipeContextItemsPage.xaml](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/8.0/UserInterface/Views/CollectionViewDemos/CollectionViewDemos/Views/Swipe/VerticalListSwipeContextItemsPage.xaml).

Comment: hello, and thank you for the consistency of your answers :) . I already knew these limitations, I asked if there was a workaround to display a menu at the location of a click on phones and tablets all the same. (DevExpress offers this functionality for example, but this library does not target Windows )

Comment: You can try `SwipeView`. :)